# Windows Server Core Docker Containers networking problem

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, docker-machine, windows-server-2019

I have 2 containers created via docker compose with the following settings:

**docker-compose.yml File:**

```yaml
version: "3.7"
services:
    web:
        image: img_web
        container_name: cont_web

    svcs:
        image: img_svcs
        container_name: cont_svcs
        depends_on:
            - web
```

**Dockerfile for img_web:**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019
WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
```

**Dockerfile for img_svcs:**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019
WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
```

After `docker-compose up -d`, and from cont_svcs container, I'm able to:

1. Ping cont_web by IP
2. Ping cont_web by hostname (container id: bf4001be1e84
   autogenerated.)

BUT **I CAN'T Ping** the **cont_web** container by its alias (web)

I inspected both containers, I can see in the network sections the following:

```js
"Networks": {
            "test_default": {
                "IPAMConfig": null,
                "Links": null,
                "Aliases": [
                    "bf4001be1e84",
                    "web"
                ],
...
```

Both containers are connected to the 'test_default' driver.

*NB: Even I can't ping the web machine by its "web" alias name within the machine itself.*

I would greatly appreciate your help and feedback.

Thanks
Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because Netbios resolution works for primary name. you can try to add 2nd Netbios name through registry: https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/the-enterprise-cloud/adding-multiple-netbios-names-for-windows-servers/

alternatively i'd recommend make a 2nd Cname record in DNS and doing the resolution with static names (might not be acceptable to you for your docker containers)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers, do you mean set the Netbios name of the CONTAINER and "OptionalName" is the host address?

Comment: yes Sameh that's what i meant. its Netbios resolution in action when you just use hostname to ping. It's where you need to find resolution

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an explicit **NAT** network to use for your deployment.
To do this, add the following at the end of your docker-compose file-

```
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nat
```

Now, try pinging the services with their service name.

If that doesn't work, there might be a Security Firewall or Internet Security application is installed in your local machine which most probably is blocking the **dockerd.exe** DNS services. Try implementing some rules to allow the TCP and UDP ports regarding **docker** based services.

Also you can try this workaround to resolve the DNS correctly- https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1976#issuecomment-418151244